# Incremental replace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

(moving this from https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/dt3zae/incremental_replace/)

I have a bunch of lines like

```js
var sz = "Testing FEATURE in FUNCTION"
```

But it's getting confusing. Is there a way I can replace `FEATURE` with `FEATURE #` where `#` counts upward? Or if I can't do that can I have it insert a line number or something?

For example, if the project has these lines across different files:

```js
// foo.js
var sz = "Testing FEATURE in FUNCTION"
// bar.js
var sz = "Testing FEATURE in FUNCTION"
// baz.js
var sz = "Testing FEATURE in FUNCTION"
```

how do we replace them all so that we have

```js
// foo.js
var sz = "Testing FEATURE in FUNCTION 1"
// bar.js
var sz = "Testing FEATURE in FUNCTION 2"
// baz.js
var sz = "Testing FEATURE in FUNCTION 3"
```

?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Find/Replace does not have memory and can't calculate, write a simple Python script to Find/Replace the simple string and add a number

Comment: It is easy to do this within a file but I doubt it is currently possible across files.  Do you want to know how to do this within a file?

Comment: @Mark it looks like your deleted answer might actually do the trick.

Comment: I could resurrect the answer but it would only work within a file.  I thought you required the numbering to be incremental across files?